# How to integrate $xy' = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have to integrate:

$xy' = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y$

It is supposed to be an homogeneous differential equation, but I can't see the variable change to make it happens. I tried:

$y' = \sqrt{1-(y/x)^2} + y/x$

And then $z = y/x$, but I don't think that that is the path.

Comment: Unless I misread something, my edit should provide the correct rewrite when dividing through by $x$...

Comment: You're almost there ["I think" - because of my next comment]. Moving the $y$ over to the LHS gives you $xy'-y$, which is the numerator of your $z'=(y/x)'$, so...

Comment: [Proceeding that way does not give you a homogeneous equation, I think, but certainly one that is separable.]

Comment: looks ok to me, carry on with the sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one is not supposed to answer in comments:

If $z=y/x$, then
$$ z'= {xy'-y\over x^2}.$$
Rearranging the original equation, and dividing by $x^2$,
one gets

$$  {xy'-y\over x^2}= {1\over x}\sqrt{1-\left({y \over x}\right)^2}$$
Therefore
$$ z'= {1\over x}\sqrt{1-z^2},$$
which is doable (separable).

I hope this helps, although this is not homogeneous, as had been requested.

Comment: I solved the equation separating variables and the solutions match the professor ones, so I assume that there is a mistake in the exercise sentence telling that it is homogeneous

Answer (score 2):

$$xy' = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y$$
$$xdy= (\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y)dx$$
$$f(x,y)dy=g(x,y)dx$$
is homogeneous if $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree:
$$f(tx,ty)=tx=tf(x,y)$$
$$g(tx,ty)=\sqrt{t^2x^2-t^2y^2}+ty=t (\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+y)=tg(x,y)$$
The two functions are homogeneous ones of degree $1$ and the substitution $y=tx$ gives a separable DE.